# How can I view message timestamps in iOS 11?

Tags: ios, messages

I have the newest version of iOS 11 on an iPhone SE. I am having no luck figuring our what time text messages were sent or received. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Drag/swipe the message window to the left.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted.  It's the correct answer.